# Use of PRXCHANGE to rename variables causes excessive replacement to happen at the end of the variable name

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I am currently trying to create a macro which will automatically replace any special characters in a variables name with an underscore. I am currently using PRXCHANGE to perform the replacement, yet I notice that when the variable gets renamed, there is extra underscores being placed at the end of the new variable name.

> Suppose we were to have two variables "dummy?" and "te!st". When I perform the replacement, the new variables are "dummy___________________________" and "    te_st___________________________". When the replacement should just be "dummy_" and "te_st", respectively.

In the sample code below, I know that if I were to add "TRIM(name)" in the PRXCHANGE function then there would not be any extra replacements occurring. The issue with doing this is that if I were to have a variable named "example! ", with a space as the final character, then I would want the variable to be renamed to "example__", with two underscores at the end. Yet by using TRIM(name), I would get "example_", with a single underscore.

N.B. I know if I change the SAS variable name policy to V7, then this would not be a problem. I am solely doing this to improve upon my SAS skills.

```
/* Generate dummy data */
option validvarname = any;
data dummy_data;
    input "dummy?"n "te!st"n;
    datalines;
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    ;
run;

/* Generate variables with the old and new variable names as entries */
data test (keep = name new_name);
    set sashelp.vcolumn;
    where libname = "WORK" and memname = "DUMMY_DATA";
    new_name = prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/", -1, name);
run;
```

Comment: Why are you using regex to replace characters? Why not use TRANSLATE()?  Are your strings using UTF-8 or some other rmulti-byte encoding?

Comment: How would you know if the trailing spaces in a variable should be considered important or not? They are certainly NOT significant in a variable name, which is your stated use case.

Comment: One note: your regex is probably wildly inefficient since it's being re-constructed on every row.  Add the `o` argument after the closing delimiter to tell SAS to only compile the regex once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is how SAS pads string variable length. While most languages have variable length strings, SAS is more akin to SQL `char` type, without the accompanying `varchar` type.  This gives SAS very good performance in some ways, due to predictable row sizes, but has some consequences.  Note that you can actually get effectively variable length strings on datasets using `options compress`, but during a data step the dataset is uncompressed.

In SAS, a string of length 10 that is assigned `"A"` will actually have value `"A         "`.  A, plus 9 spaces.  Not null characters, actual space characters.  That usually doesn't matter, as SAS is written in many ways to ignore those trailing spaces (so `"A" = "A    " = "A                   "`), but in this particular case it does matter (since you're transforming the space character).

You can use the `trim` function to remove the spaces *during* execution, though it will still be stored with the spaces afterwards of course.

```
new_name = prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/", -1, trim(name));
```

Note that `trim` cannot return a null value, it will *always* return a single space, so if that's a possibility, you should wrap this in a check for `missing` (a string variable with only spaces = missing).

```
if not missing(name) then do;
  new_name = prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/", -1, trim(name));    
end;
else new_name = ' ';
```

There is a `trimn` function that can return a length 0 string, but there's no reason to do the prxchange if it's missing - this will save time.

Comment: There's just two points I'd like further clarification upon. The first one is when you mention that `trim` will always return a single space and that the use of the `trim` function during execution will result in the space being stored afterwards. Is this using the concept that in SAS `"A"` has the same value as `"A     "`? Thus, after using `trim`, SAS will still read the entry as having spaces at the end? The second point is that am I correct in assuming there is no way to ensure that `"A  "` gets replaced into `"A__"`, specifically because SAS reads `"A  "` to be equivalent to `"A"`?

Comment: No; Trim will always return at least one character; meaning `trim(‘ ‘)` will return a space. If there is a non space character then it will return no trailing spaces.

Comment: And on the second point; yes, ‘`A’` and `’A ‘` are identical to SAS if the variable is two bytes long, no way to differentiate. You’d have to add a string terminator yourself (which you could do).  Ie, find a character not used for anything else (maybe `’0A’x` , the line feed) and insert it after the desired space. But that depends on you having a way to identify that the space is desired. I probably would instead have a metadata table that stored the length of the value for each record - then check that and use it to pad the spaces.

Comment: Use `trimn()` to return an empty string when the values are all spaces.

Comment: @Tom That's true, but I'm not sure `prxchange` plays well with `trimn` - only some string functions can deal with null strings as arguments.  Either way I think better to use an IF to check, since PRXCHANGE is expensive.

Comment: @Tom I did verify PRXCHANGE works with TRIMN, so that _would_ work, though I'd still use the IF block for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern about trailing spaces on variable names it not valid. Trailing spaces on variable names are not significant. This data step creates only one variable.

```
376   options validvarname=any;
377   data test;
378     'xxx'n = 1;
379     'xxx 'n= 2;
380   run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.07 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```